# C# - Regex - separate N words

Tags: c#, regex

I need to capture N phone number and name in the standard phrase:
"Please write down my phone: 999999 - Vinicius Lacerda Andrioni and I have 90 years old."
"Please write down my phone: 888888 - michael jordan and I have 60 years old."

the output should be:
string: 999999, 888888
string: Vinicius Lacerda Andrioni, michael jordan

```
string pattern = @"phone: (?<after>\w+)";
string input = "Please write down my phone: 999999 - Vinicius Lacerda Andrioni and I have 90 years old.";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
{ 
    MessageBox.Show(matches[i].Groups["after"].ToString());
}
```

Output: 999999
Output: ???

Comment: I think you have an XY problem here. You've found the starting point of your name (everything after the phone number) just by finding the phone number. What you wanted to do is pretty simple if you don't try to use regex. You can use `split(' ')` to then get it separated into words, then just take the first `N` elements of that result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simpler:

```
String Input = "Please write down my phone: 999999 - Vinicius Lacerda Andrioni and I have 90 years old.";

String[] Results = Input.Split(new String[] {": ", "- ", " and" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

// of course you'll want to add error checking....
MessageBox.Show(Results[1]);
MessageBox.Show(Results[2]);
```

Comment: if the phrase were not so?
Input String = "Please write down my phone: 999999";
just as you'd get the phone?

Comment: Yes.   _Always_ check for the existence of an array element before trying to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"phone:\s?(?<phone>\w+)\s?[-]\s?(?<name>.*)\s?and");
string input = "Please write down my phone: 999999 - Vinicius Lacerda Andrioni and I have 90 years old.";
var v= regex.Match(input);
Console.WriteLine("Phone = " + v.Groups["phone"].ToString() + " Name = " + v.Groups["name"].ToString());
```

As I understand you want to get the name as well as the phone number from this standard format. So, just extend your expression to include a second group for the name part, and then retrieve the value the same way you did for phone.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/LQX90685)